# Is やんろー a version of 野郎?

Tags: meaning, video-games

I’d like to make sure that I understood this correctly.

> このやんろー！！

appears in Cave Story (洞窟物語) game. トロ子 calls this after the player enters her hideout. I’d suspect the word やんろー to be a version of 野郎, but I could not find any reference supporting this.

Can I consider it an emotionally flavored version of?

> この野郎！！

I found some occurrences of やんろー, やんろ, やんろう or even このやんろー, but none with a context that would help me. ヤンロー is apparently some kind of Chinese lamb meat dish.

[image: Screenshot saying このやんろー！！]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it seems to be a variant of やろー (野郎). You probably have seen `っ` randomly inserted between kana for emphasis (e.g. あっつい, きったねぇ, まっじで). I think ん in used instead here because ろ cannot be preceded by っ.